# Had to change precision for textures, why?

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, shader

I worked a little bit on my fragment shader to allow both texture rendering as well as color rendering. After I made the changes, all my textures were very pixelated (like an old 8-bit game) and I had to ramp up the precision for the texture coordinates to medium. This also gave me a performance hit. I just don't understand why I suddenly had to change the precision in the first place.

Here is the "original" shader:

```
varying lowp vec2 TexCoordOut;
uniform sampler2D Texture;

uniform lowp float opacity;

void main(void) {
    gl_FragColor = opacity * texture2D(Texture, TexCoordOut);
}
```

This is how the shader looks after the changes:

```
varying mediump vec2 TexCoordOut;
uniform sampler2D Texture;

uniform lowp vec4 color;
uniform lowp float opacity;
uniform int colorRender;

void main(void) {
    if (colorRender == 1)
    {
        gl_FragColor = color;
    } else {
        gl_FragColor = opacity * texture2D(Texture, TexCoordOut);
    }
}
```

Comment: The performance hit is not related to mediump.  lowp is even slower on iOS than mediump.  Branching is slow.  ints are slow.

Comment: @Jessy: lowp should never be slower than mediump (unless the driver is broken), as the driver/hardware is free to use more precision if it wishes (and it should, if it would be faster).  The spec only specifies minimum precision requirements.

Comment: Call it broken if you want.  I'll definitely concede that the lack of documentation about the drivers is garbage:

"Many built-in functions use medium-precision inputs and outputs. If your application provides low-precision floating-point values as parameters or assigns the results to a low-precision floating-point variable, the shader may have to include additional instructions to convert the values."

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html

Comment: @Jessy - lowp can indeed be faster on iOS in many cases, particularly with vector operations. I've seen cases where I achieved nearly an order of magnitude improvement using lowp over mediump, but this is something you almost need to profile on a case-by-case basis. Thankfully, it's pretty easy to change around precision when testing.

Comment: I'm not saying lowp isn't the fastest option in almost every case, for fragment shader calculations.  It is.  I'm saying it's pointless to use it for non-dependent texture coordinates.

Comment: Yeah, I just reread my original comment.  Oops.  Now I don't understand how someone would have taken what I meant from it.  I was specifically referring to the switch from lowp to mediump for TexCoordOut.  That should result in either no performance change, or a gain, at least on PowerVR hardware, in my experience.  You have conflicting results?

Comment: @Jessy - Yeah, I almost always use highp for texture coordinates and vertex positions, because of precision artifacts from lowp and even mediump. You definitely see conversion overhead there when going to lowp, but sometimes that can be offset be gains elsewhere. I think Chris and I just reacted to the broader statement in your first comment, which you clarified later. The relationship between precision and performance varies even between various GPUs in the iOS device line, so I always end up profiling different permutations to determine what works best in a given shader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You blame the performance loss on switching to mediump, but you've also added branching to the shader.  Given that every fragment for a single draw call will always take the same path, you should just have two different shaders, each without branching.

Comment: Yes, branching in the fragment shader has a huge effect on performance on iOS. Splitting into two shader programs is the way to approach this.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize this. So I just create one Shader like the old one and one only for the colors and just call a different shader in the different scenarios?

Comment: I now implemented two different shader programs. This gave me a little performance boost. So I guess it worked. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 7):

`lowp` only has about 8 bits of precision minimum, so if your texture is 128x128 or larger you'll start to see artifacts, and if your texture is bigger than 256x256, some texels will be lost completely (the severe pixillation you describe).

`mediump` has a minimum of 11 bits of precision, so should be fine up to 1024x1024 texels (though being a floating-point type, you can get pixellation if your texture coordinates are unnormalized)

`highp` has a minimum of 24 bits of precision (same as IEEE single-precision float) so is even better.

Note that these precisions are minimums according to the spec -- hardware may use more precision for any of these if it would be faster.

Comment: @jesusgumbau: the question is about precision qualifiers on texture coordinates, not on texels.  So the size of the texture is quite relevant, while the texel bit depth is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

The texture coordinates are evaluated for each fragment separately. However with low precision numbers are quantized down on a per-fragment base, which means that a lot of neighboring fragments will actually evaluate to the very same quantized texture coordinate. In principle the precision for a texture coordinate variable must allow for more quantization steps, than the number of pixels/texels in the texture in the sampled direction.